# Master Page not working on single page but only in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, master-pages

So I put up my digital portfolio (asp c# web application) recently and realized that the master page does not work correctly on my "Portfolio" page of my website, and only when it is being viewed in IE. Chrome, firefox, and safari work fine as well as every other page in IE.

Not sure why it is not working, i checked syntax and can not find a reason. Does anybody have any ideas?

Portfolio.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" CodeBehind="Portfolio.aspx.cs" Inherits="PortfolioApplication.Portfolio" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" >
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/portfolioLayout.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js-image-slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/popup.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function populateSlider(sliderNum) {
            //Note: If the slider container has been set as invisible(e.g. display:none;), make sure set it visible before reload the imageSlider
            setSliderMarkup(sliderNum);
            imageSlider.reload();
        }
        function setSliderMarkup(sliderNum) {
            var sliderFrame = document.getElementById("popUp");

            switch (sliderNum) {
                case 1:
                    sliderFrame.innerHTML = '<div id="slider">' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/VacationWidget/vacationSlider1.jpg" width="989px" height="691" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/VacationWidget/vacationSlider2.jpg" width="989px" height="691" />' +
                        '</div>';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sliderFrame.innerHTML = '<div id="slider"><img src="Pictures/Projects/FlashPortfolio/portfolioSlider1.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/FlashPortfolio/portfolioSlider2.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/FlashPortfolio/portfolioSlider3.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/FlashPortfolio/portfolioSlider4.jpg" />' +
                        '</div>';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sliderFrame.innerHTML = '<div id="slider"><img src="Pictures/Projects/A1Auto/upholsterySlider1.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/A1Auto/upholsterySlider2.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/A1Auto/upholsterySlider3.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/A1Auto/upholsterySlider4.jpg" />' +
                        '</div>';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sliderFrame.innerHTML = '<div id="slider"><img src="Pictures/Projects/Renatus/renatusSlider1.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/Renatus/renatusSlider2.jpg" />' +
                        '<img src="Pictures/Projects/Renatus/renatusSlider3.jpg" />' +
                            '</div>';
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div class ="content">
        <h1>My Recent Projects!</h1>
        <div id="project1" class="project">
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Pictures/Projects/VacationWidget/VacationWidget.png" CssClass="projectImage" OnClientClick="populateSlider(1); return false" />
            <div id="project1Content" class="projectContent">
                <h1>Vacation Widget</h1>
                <p>Posted on: Saturday, October 28th, 2012</p>
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <p>This vacation widget... </p>
            </div>
        </div>                
        <div id="project2" class="projectOther">
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Pictures/Projects/FlashPortfolio/FlashPortfolio1.png" CssClass="projectImage" OnClientClick="populateSlider(2); return false" />
            <div id="Div2" class="projectContent">
                <h1>Flash Portfolio</h1>
                <p>Posted on: Saturday, October 28th, 2012</p>
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <p>This project was designed...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="project3" class="project">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Pictures/Projects/A1Auto/Upholstry.png" CssClass="projectImage" OnClientClick="populateSlider(3); return false" />
            <div id="Div3" class="projectContent">
                <h1>A1-Auto Upholstery</h1>
                <p>Posted on: Saturday, October 28th, 2012</p>
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <p>Recently modified with a few JavaScript touch ups...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="project4" class="projectOther">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Pictures/Projects/Renatus/bestTravel.jpg" CssClass="projectImage" OnClientClick="populateSlider(4); return false" />
            <div id="Div4" class="projectContent">
                <h1>Renatus Travel Desktop Application</h1>
                <p>Posted on: Saturday, October 28th, 2012</p>
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <p>Best Travel is a fictional company...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageViewerPopup" id="popUp" style="color:blue; width:691px" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="fade"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to say anything without looking at your code. Paste some code to get help from gurus.

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: the links in the master page are missing

Comment: Here is a link to the page: http://troyloberger.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple HTML and CSS validation errors on your Portfolio page.

The specific issue in Internet Explorer 8 disappears when you remove the "width: 2200px" from the div element with the ID "background", and I can't see that this width is needed, but I would also encourage you to look at the validation issues (see [HTML validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftroyloberger.cloudapp.net%2FPortfolio.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and [CSS validation results](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftroyloberger.cloudapp.net%2FPortfolio.aspx&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)) whilst fixing the issue.

I would also suggest that you replace the input buttons in the nav menu with more semantic HyperLinks - these will be more accessible and resolve the problem where the page URL isn't updated until the second postback after clicking the nav menu button (for why this is happening, look at the page lifecycle and event handling, the order in which events fire in your C# code).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Another question for you since you seem well veteraned in this area: I am getting errors for the div being in the wrong place but really they are in the javascript for a popup. Is this still bad practice? It is being used by setting the inner html of an element.